# Invoke Static Method of a .NET Generic Class in MATLAB?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, generics

How do you invoke a static method of a .NET generic class in MATLAB?

For example, how would I invoke the static method `Create` shown below?

```
public class A<T> {

    internal A() {      
    }

    public static A<T> Create() {
        return new A<T>();
    }
}
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brz16z_-1.html talks about invoking a static generic method of a generic class, but it does not show how to invoke a static non-generic method of a generic class.

Answer (score 2):

So on that link you have, it says:

> Invoke Generic Functions of a Generic Class
>   If a generic method uses the same parameterized type as the generic class, you can call the function directly on the class object. If the generic uses a different type than the class, use the NET.invokeGenericMethod function.

So seems like you should be able to do:

```
genClsDef = NET.GenericClass('A','System.Double');
ret = NET.invokeGenericMethod(genClsDef,'A','System.Double');
```

Comment: NET.GenericClass returns a NET.GenericClass, it does not expose the methods of the generic class.

Comment: @mark - Yeah I thought that might be the case.  I removed the direct call and added the invoke call

Comment: NET.invokeGenericMethod does not work either. It's not a generic method.

Comment: This might help, it uses the COM interface [Using C# functions and forms in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16549)

Comment: Thanks. I sure hope that's not the only way.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work to invoke a static method of a generic non-static class:

```
c = NET.createGeneric('A',{'System.Double'});
d = c.Create()
```